# Replacing mean value from one dataset to another

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to normalize the missing values in matrix. Here is the code.

```
ds1 = pd.read_table('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/c5530bd1baecb192e148/raw/ds1', sep=' ', header=None)

# and ds2 is your dataset2, [0, 1] as columns etc.
ds2 = pd.read_table('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/karimkhanp/1692f1f76718c35e939f/raw/6f6b348ab0879b702e1c3c5e362e9d2062e9e9bc/ds2', header=None, sep=' ')
ds2_mean = ds2.groupby(0).mean()
#Rounding the float value
ds2_mean = ds2_mean.apply(np.round)
#ds2_mean = ds2.groupby(0).std()
#print ds2_mean
ds1.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
#print ds1
print ds2_mean[1]
ds1 = ds1.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(ds2_mean[1]))
```

Last line should replace the values in dataset1 by mean values from `ds2_mean[1]`. But it does not do. Anything wrong here?
And after that can I replace NaN with the average value of it's neighbours in dataset1?

Comment: Are you wanting this: `ds1 = ds1.fillna(ds2[1])` instead of your last line?

Comment: it does wrong. For any x in dataset2 it has mapped value in col2. It should replace all values of x in ds1 by mapped value. But this also does not do it

Comment: Sorry can you explain clearer, what are you mapping from what to what exactly? By default fillna will use the index so how do you want the mapping from `ds2` to map to the missing values in `ds1`? Are you wanting to map using the values in `ds2[0]` as the index lookup? So use the index from `ds1` find value in `ds2[0]` and return `ds2[1]`?

Comment: Also are you using multiple accounts? you've posted the same comment from user123 as well as Aamirkhan?

Comment: @EdChum Ya that was a mistake, any way using single account only

Comment: Well you're trying to edit your own post using the other account, please edit using this account and explain clearly your desired output

Comment: yes, I want to use the index from ds1 find value in ds2[0] and replace it with ds2[1]" sorry for inconvenience