# Any function in numpy/pandas/python to search and replace

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, pandas

I have matrix of 4x4 like this 
ds1=

```
4  13  6  9 
7  12  5  7
7  0  4  22  
9  8  12  0
```

and other file with two columns:
ds2 =

```
4  1
5  3
6  1
7  2
8  2
9  3
12  1
13  2
22  3

ds1 = ds1.apply(lambda x: ds2_mean[1] if [condition])
```

What condition to be added to compare and check that elements from ds1 and ds2 are equal?

I want col1 value from 2nd matrix to be replaced by col2 value in matrix 1, so resultant matrix should look like

```
1  2  1  3
2  1  3  2
2  0  1  3
3  2  1  0
```

please see [Replacing mean value from one dataset to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048317/replacing-mean-value-from-one-dataset-to-another) this does not answer my question

Comment: Please post your code, what you've tried, what errors you're experiencing, etc. Also explain why and what part of the answer you linked doesn't work for you and clarify your question a bit. Also, grammar, capitalization, punctuation. ;)

Comment: @Will: I updated, I appreciate if you give any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with `numpy arrays`, you could do this -

```
# Make a copy of ds1 to initialize output array 
out = ds1.copy()

# Find out the row indices in ds2 that have intersecting elements between 
# its first column and ds1
_,C = np.where(ds1.ravel()[:,None] == ds2[:,0])

# New values taken from the second column of ds2 to be put in output
newvals = ds2[C,1]

# Valid positions in output array to be changed
valid = np.in1d(ds1.ravel(),ds2[:,0])

# Finally make the changes to get desired output
out.ravel()[valid] = newvals
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [79]: ds1
Out[79]: 
array([[ 4, 13,  6,  9],
       [ 7, 12,  5,  7],
       [ 7,  0,  4, 22],
       [ 9,  8, 12,  0]])

In [80]: ds2
Out[80]: 
array([[ 4,  1],
       [ 5,  3],
       [ 6,  1],
       [ 7,  2],
       [ 8,  2],
       [ 9,  3],
       [12,  1],
       [13,  2],
       [22,  3]])

In [81]: out
Out[81]: 
array([[1, 2, 1, 3],
       [2, 1, 3, 2],
       [2, 0, 1, 3],
       [3, 2, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: thanks a ton, could you please help one more thing. Getting average of neighbours in matrix elements where if neighbour element is `na` then skip that neighbour

Comment: this is mcode for 3x3, but for large matrix like 1kx1k, this is not feasible :   `  def neighbors(i,j,a):
        return [a[i][j-1], a[i][(j+1)%len(a[0])], a[i-1][j], a[(i+1)%len(a)][j]]
    [[np.mean(neighbors(i,j,a)) for j in range(len(a[0]))] for i in range(len(a))]`

Comment: @bigdata That sounds like a totally different problem to tackle. Could you post that as a new question?

Comment: @Divakar: thanks but I am getting `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ravel'` here

Comment: @Aamirkhan You need to convert that to a numpy array as the solution states at the top. Probably np.array(ds1) and so on might work

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution. Using DataFrame.replace() function.

```
df1.replace(to_replace= df2[0].tolist(), value= df2[1].tolist, inplace=True)
```