# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ravel'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to test panda program which works fine on other system.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
ds1 = pd.read_table('data.txt', sep=' ', header=None)
ds2 = pd.read_table('Dataset.txt', header=None, sep=' ')
out = ds1.copy()

_,C = np.where(ds1.ravel()[:,None] == ds2[:,0])

newvals = ds2[C,1]

# Valid positions in output array to be changed
valid = np.in1d(ds1.ravel(),ds2[:,0])

# Finally make the changes to get desired output
out.ravel()[valid] = newvals
print out
```

when I tried it gives,

```
    _,C = np.where(ds1.ravel()[:,None] == ds2[:,0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1947, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ravel'
```

**Update**

sample raw data:

```
ds1 = pd.read_table('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/karimkhanp/9527bad750fbe75e072c/raw/ds1', sep=' ', header=None)
ds2 = pd.read_table('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/karimkhanp/1692f1f76718c35e939f/raw/6f6b348ab0879b702e1c3c5e362e9d2062e9e9bc/ds2', header=None, sep=' ')
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to compare here, it looks like you're trying to use numpy like slicing on a df but this won't work

Comment: The shapes of your dfs are completely different ds1 is `(40,1001)` whilst ds2 is `(4000,2)` you can't compare the arrays uing your method you'll need to explain clearly what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @EdChum: I am trying to implement as described on this list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067356/any-function-in-numpy-pandas-python-to-search-and-replace

Comment: I think you need to understand what that question is trying to solve and how that relates to your data for instance the following is cleaned up: `_,C = np.where(ds1.values.ravel()[:,None] == ds2.values[:,0])

newvals = ds2.loc[C,1]

# Valid positions in output array to be changed
valid = np.in1d(ds1.values.ravel(),ds2.values[:,0])
` but the last line will fail as you're trying to compare str values with floats which makes no sense, 6 of your columns are of str dtype

Comment: @EdChum: `ds2` is same in both of our case, in `ds1` I just have large `matrix`, cam you please suggest some solution

Comment: @EdChum: I updated datasets too

Comment: You'll need to filter out the columns that are not numeric and then perform a lookup

Comment: @EdChum: all columns are same, numeric only. https://gist.githubusercontent.com/karimkhanp/9527bad750fbe75e072c/raw/ds1 still it gives issue

Answer (score 1):

Well the error is pretty clear, you want to access the numpy `values` attribute:

```
_,C = np.where(ds1.values.ravel()[:,None] == ds2[:,0])
```

Comment: this gives `TypeError: unhashable type ` on same line